# Moving stack to specific place

Tags: c, linux, x86, stack

How to move my stack to specific virtual address? For example I would like for my stack to be 40960 big, and beginning in the address 0x355480. I tried playing with setcontext, but I'd like to know whether there is a 'standard' way to do that:

```
ucontext_t cont;
bool flag = false;
getcontext (&cont);
if(!flag){
  void* a = mmap((void*)0x34B000, 81920, PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
  cont.uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ESP] = 0x355000;
  flag = true;
  setcontext(&cont);
}
```

Comment: You can implement a function i.e. switch_stack in assembly and assign the register esp with your specified value.

Comment: You cannot really move an existing stack at random; there can be absolute pointers to stack variables everywhere.

Comment: but i can do it at the beginning of the program, when nothing important there is yet.

Comment: **Perhaps**. But you cannot really **return** from this function, just `exit`.

Comment: You said you need to copy the stack; and it didn't copy - but that is what does not work. You cannot copy a stack - you can only make a new stack.

Comment: good point, i'll update my answer

Comment: well I just want my stack to be somewhere else than default place.

Comment: (I said "there can be absolute pointers in the stack" - then I realized that of course there are absolute pointers; all the return addresses and basepointers and such are usually absolute pointers, so you definitely cannot copy a stack under any circumstances.)

Comment: One note; if you move the stack you will likely lose the guard page that the OS places at the bottom of the stack to allow it to dynamically grow when you fill it up. This could cause significant issues if you do overrun the stack, and I believe it would kill your program with a SIGSEGV.

Answer (score -1):

Code below sets the stack pointer around the mmap we did before and allows us to work on it in main2 function:

```
bool flag = false;
int argc2;
char ** argv2;
int main2(){
    ...
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    argc2 = argc;
    argv2 = argv;
    ucontext_t cont;
    getcontext (&cont);
    if(!flag){
      void* a = mmap((void*)0x34B000, 81920, PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
      if(a == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmapfail");
        return 1;
      }
      cont.uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ESP] = 0x355000;
      flag = true;
      setcontext(&cont);
    } else{
      exit(main2());
    }
}
```

Comment: For this to be a valid answer, it has to explain how/why it answers the question.  Also, from reading the man page for `setcontext(3)`, you may need a compiler barrier to make sure the store to `flag` actually happens before the call to `setcontext`.  Although probably not if it's a global, rather than static.